# Tomcat9.exe (Apache Tomcat 9 Windows service) kill/stop child process when service is stopped

Tags: tomcat

It seems that Tomcat9.exe (Apache Tomcat 9 Windows service) stops or kills child processes when the service is stopped. This does not happen if the service is killed. With Tomcat7.exe, this did not happen. Is it possible to ensure that the service does not kill processes when stopped?

I tried to create a child process that stops the service and then performs other operations. When the service stops, the child process is terminated. I would expect the child process to continue running, as was the case with Tomcat7.exe  (Apache Tomcat 7 Windows service)